# Installing git from source on OS X - exec-path error

Tags: mac-osx, installation, git, source

I'm trying to install git from source using

```
make prefix=/Users/gareth/local/git install
```

but after installation nothing works properly, the commands all fail with, for example

```
git: 'pull' is not a git-command. See 'git --help'.
```

After some research I found out that the most obvious problem is this output:

```
$ git --exec-path
/Users/gareth
```

but I don't know why the exec-path is set to my home directory. The binaries are all in what appears to be the correct place, `~/local/git/libexec/git-core/git*`

How can I work out what went wrong, and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you do ./configure --prefix=/Users/gareth/local/git ?

Comment: The INSTALL file, and the help I looked for on IRC, suggested that the make prefix= would be sufficient. Even so, I get the same result when I use that ./configure parameter

Comment: See also the same question (different user) on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1465398/git-pull-now-broken-on-snow-leopard

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is not really what you're looking for, but I would recommend you [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/).

With it, you can quickly build projects from sources and keeping them up-to-date. It will also handle any dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're building Git the wrong way. You should be donig something like:

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/gareth/local/git
make
make install
```

Then make sure the `git` binary is on your path (and possibly `git-receive-pack` if you want to push via ssh from another machine).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the answer to your question, but as a workaround, consider installing [Git for OS X](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/).  [There is a [Build-Your-Own](http://code.google.com/p/git-osx-installer/wiki/BuildYourOwn) page on the wiki, but I'm not sure if it'll provide enough detail for what you want to do.]